# How to set remote access for user in mysql server?

Tags: mysql, spring

When I create a user in mysql, following this:

```
CREATE USER IF NOT EXISTS 'devadmin'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'admindev';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON developerparse.* TO 'devadmin'@'%';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

I can join into mysql:

```
mysql -u devadmin -p
```

but I need set remote access for user, so when I set the host to '%':

```
CREATE USER IF NOT EXISTS 'devadmin'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'admindev';
```

and trying to join mysql, I get an error:

```
MySQL ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'devadmin'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

---

**How to resolved that?**

---

table of users accounts:

```
select user, host from mysql.user;

+------------------+-----------+
| user             | host      |
+------------------+-----------+
| devadmin         | %         |
| devuser          | %         |
| prodadmin        | %         |
| produser         | %         |
| testadmin        | %         |
| testuser         | %         |
| debian-sys-maint | localhost |
| developer        | localhost |
| mysql.session    | localhost |
| mysql.sys        | localhost |
| root             | localhost |
+------------------+-----------+
```

Answer (score 1):

% mean this user can be from any host.  localhost, the user can only from that server.  This can be usefull for root by example (security purpose).  root@localhost mean nobody can connect with root user, except from the server itself.

Comment: So, how connect to database from local in spring ptoject, if user hafe '%' host parameter? This is main question

Comment: Do you have multiple devadmin users?  one with localhost host, and one with % host?  And both users have a different password.  That would explain the error you got.  Il you have the user with localhost, remove it.  MySQL will then use the user with % host.

Comment: I will edited my question and add to him table with user. Look please

Comment: Why you are trying to log with `Bill` username?  You still use that command : `mysql -u devadmin -p`?

Comment: I tried many things on my machine.  The only way I got this, is to type a wrong password.

Comment: Can you test this script, please? And do connect into this accounts https://gitlab.com/hhlTer/parserJob/raw/devbranch/test.sh?inline=false